# 58mm thermal receipt printer empty area problem

Tags: thermal-printer

my web based application prints receipts from browser. But at the end of page and content, thermal rolls paper approximately 15mm. there is nothing at this area. I checked margins and set them all zero. At windows printer settings there is no parameter about this. Where can I look for solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is hardware dependent due to the spacing between the thermal printhead and the paper cutter.

Some printer vendors and models have mechanisms to reduce the gap.

Please contact your printer vendor or distributor.

If there is no function to reduce such a gap, generally, before cutting the paper, print a fixed content such as a store logo for the next receipt.

---

Or, if such blanks exist before the paper cut, you may have created the print data in page mode and specified the size of the print area larger than the size required for the print data.

In that case, correct the calculation so that the print area size is the intended size.